# servlet error on console doesn't redirect to error page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, redirect

I have a problem when I try to enter duplicate entries as you can see in the servlet below. The problem is that tomcat shows the duplicate error but the servlet doesn't redirect to the desired error page (dup_organism.jsp). However I have no problem when I enter a new record and redirect to another page, while the code is pretty much the same.
I have this servlet:

```
package package_ergasia;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


public class AddOrganism extends HttpServlet 
{
@Override
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException 
   {
    response.setContentType("text/html");    
    Connection connection= null;    
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "ergasia";    
    String user = "root";
    String password = "password";
    String org_id = request.getParameter("id");  
    String oname = request.getParameter("oname");    


        try {   
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, user, password);


            Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM organism") ;

            while(resultset.next()){

                if(resultset.getString("org_id").equalsIgnoreCase(org_id)){
                    String contextPath= "http://localhost:8084/secured";
                    response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(contextPath + "/dup_organism.jsp"));
                }


                    else{
                        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO organism (org_id,organismName) VALUES (?,?)");
                        ps.setString(1, org_id);
                        ps.setString(2, oname);                     
                        ps.executeUpdate(); 
                        String contextPath= "http://localhost:8084/secured";
                        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(contextPath + "/all_organisms.jsp"));
                    }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "info";
    }
}
```

this is the error page dup_organism.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<html>  
    <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/mystyle.css">
    <title>Duplicate entry</title>  
    </head>  
<body>
          <h1>Error</h1>
          <% String org_id = request.getParameter("org_id"); %>

            <h2><div align="center">
            <br><br><br>
            Duplicate data <br> @Organism Id: 
            <% out.println(org_id); %>
            </div></h2>      
</body> 
</html>
```

browser shows nothing (still on servlet page) and tomcat shows the following error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '02' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem why your getting null is that your using response.sendRedirect which creates a new instance of request and response object. you can do any one of the following:

1. Replace it with request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
2. Set the Org_id in the session object and retrieve it in the jsp.

Comment: I couldn't get the first one to work but after I set the session object it works like a charm, thank you.